# Integration error from Plot3D

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to visualize diffusion distribution from an equilateral triangle with 45 degrees. Assuming that diffusion is a Gaussian with `sigma=1` this should do:

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := Integrate[E^(-x^2 - y^2), {x, -a, -a + c}, {y, -b, x - b + a}] / Pi
```

where `{a,b}` are the coordinates and `c` is the size of the triangle's side.

A quick sanity check seems reasonable:

```
f[0, 0, 10] // N
```

returns `0.125` as expected.

However, this command:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y, 10], {x, -3, 13}, {y, -3, 13}]
```

generates these errors:

```
Integrate::ilim: "Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {-2.998856`,2.998856`,12.998856`}"

NIntegrate::dupv: "Duplicate variable -2.99886 found in NIntegrate[1.54405*10^-8,{-2.99886,2.99886,12.9989},{-2.99886,2.99886,-2.99886}]."

Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {-1.856,1.856,11.856}. 

NIntegrate::itraw: "Raw object -1.856 cannot be used as an iterator."
```

Could you tell what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I think that the dummy integration variables in the definition of `f` get mixed up with the later arguments of the same. You could define `f` using `\[FormalX]` and `\[FormalY]` as integration variables in order to avoid trouble.

Comment: @b.gatessucks is <strike>probably</strike> right here, since the plotting functions all use `Block` to scope their variables.  I'm lazy though, so I go for `xx` and `yy` when I can't use `x` and `y`

Comment: Thanks, @b.gatessucks, I think you are right. Changed `x,y` to `xx,yy` as @JasonB suggested, and now instead of outputting the errors it's running... and running... and still running... :-)

Comment: @Michael, since you are mainly interested to plot, and not looking for an analytic solution, you could switch to numeric integration.  `ClearAll[f]; 
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[E^(-x^2 - y^2), {x, -a, -a + c}, {y, -b, x - b + a}]/Pi`, plots in a little under a minute

Comment: @JasonB: thanks!

Comment: a bit of an aside to the question, but its often worthwhile with try to do such multidimensional integrals as nested 1d integrals. In this case the integral over `y` can be done analytically (`Integrate`), then you are left with a much faster 1-d `NIntegrate` over x.