# How to prevent name clash between arguments of different functions?

Tags: functions, scoping

Per comments, including here the description of the problem lifted from [another site](http://weaklyreachable.blogspot.com/2007/06/mathematica-pure-function-scope-problem_2182.html):

> Mathematica Pure Function Scope Problem
>
> Consider this snippet:
>
> ```
> f[x_] := g[Function[a, x]];
> g[fn_] := Module[{h}, h[a_] := fn[a]; h[0]];
> f[999]
> ```
>
> Executing this sequence generates errors messages:
>
> ```
> Function::flpar: Parameter specification {0} in Function[{0},999] should be a symbol or a list of symbols. (x3)
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. (x4)
>
> Hold[Function[{0},999][0]]
> ```
>
> However, if you change the name of the function variable in the first
>   line from a to z, then all works as expected:
>
> ```
> f[x_] := g[Function[z, x]];
> f[999]
>
> => 999
> ```
>
> Another workaround is to compile the function:
>
> ```
> f[x_] := g[Compile[a, x]];
> f[999]
>
> => 999
> ```
>
> The problem appears to be caused by a name conflict between the pure
>   function's argument a and the helper function h's argument a.  This is
>   a really nasty problem because the definitions are completely separate
>   -- one would have to perform a global code analysis to turn up such problems.

I'm a relatively new user of `Mathematica` and have already ran into that problem, asked and answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124706/integration-error-from-plot3d).

I'm used to `C++`; in `C++` and most other programming languages) local scope of function arguments and local scope of most variables prevents variable name clash between different functions.

Thus the question: how does one prevent the above problem in `Mathematica`?

Comment: It may seem a pain, but please [make the question self-contained](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18669/should-posts-be-self-contained).

Comment: @MichaelE2: OK.

Comment: Related: [How does Table behave differently?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126427/18476)

Comment: `f[999] // Trace // Quiet` makes clear what's going on, I think, for those who can read `Trace` output.  Both `a` are renamed to prevent clashes, but renamed to the same thing `a$`, which causes the clash.  Bummer.  This language area is not my forte, but it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question asks about two distinct problems, with different remedies.

**Problem #1: "Mathematica Pure Function Scope Problem"**

I encountered this problem in a non-trivial body of *Mathematica* code and it took me hours to isolate it and fix it.  I reported the issue to WRI at the time.  They acknowledged the bug and suggested that the work-around is to avoid the use of named arguments in pure functions.  That is, rewrite `Function[{x, y}, ... x ... y ...]` as `... # ... #2 ... &`.  I now avoid named arguments in pure functions like the plague on account of the trauma of the whole experience.

At first this sounds like an old joke (Patient: *It hurts when I do this.*  Doctor: *Don't do that.*), but I find in practice is rarely causes me any grief.  The rare exception is when I wish to nest two pure functions and want to inject a value into the inner scope (for examples, see [(16947)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16947/142) or [(38393)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38393/142)).  The usual work-around is to use named arguments, e.g.

```
Function[{x}, ... Function[{y}, ... x ...] ...]
```

but since this is plague-infested I usually just create a regular (non-pure) named function or look for an alternate technique such as using replacement rules.  Again, I emphasize that I find such cases to be very rare.

**Problem #2: Free Variables Within Function Definitions**

The second problem from the [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124706/142) concerns the errors arising from the following expressions:

```
f[a_, b_, c_] := Integrate[E^(-x^2 - y^2), {x, -a, -a + c}, {y, -b, x - b + a}] / Pi

Plot3D[f[x, y, 10], {x, -3, 13}, {y, -3, 13}]

(* ... many errors ... *)
```

In this case, the problem lies with the definition of `f`.  It references the free variable symbols `x` and `y`.  When the function evaluates, these symbols will take on whatever values they happen to have in the enclosing scope.  In the case at hand `x` will take on various values between -3 and 13.  But `Integrate` wants `x` to be a variable name, not some real value.  Hence the errors.

The fix is to use `Module` to localize `x` and `y`:

```
f[a_, b_, c_] :=
  Module[{x, y}
  , Integrate[E^(-x^2 - y^2), {x, -a, -a + c}, {y, -b, x - b + a}] / Pi
  ]
```

*(but note the comments on the linked question: this multidimensional integral is computationally expensive to evaluate and one would be wise to find another method to perform the integration)*

I think it is fair so say that most users are surprised sooner or later by the need to localize the integration variables in `Integrate` and the iterators in functions like `Table`, `Plot`, etc.  This issue is discussed at length in [(94061)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94061/142) and [(126683)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126683/142), including discussion about the *Mathematica* design decisions that make such localization necessary in the first place.