# very simple but unexpected aspect of Function[ ]

Tags: functions, function-construction, variable-definitions, built-in-symbols

I've always thought

```
(2#+1)&
```

and

```
Function[x,2x+1]
```

are interchangeable in common sense. But,

```
Clear[F]; F[x_] := (2 # + 1) &[x^2]; F[3]
(* 19 *)

Clear[F]; F[a_] := Function[x, 2 x + 1][a^2]; F[3]
(* 19 *)

Clear[F]; F[x_] := Function[x, 2 x + 1][x^2]; F[3]
(* Function::flpar: Parameter specification 3 in Function[3,2 3+1] should be a symbol or a list of symbols. *)
(* Function::flpar: Parameter specification 3 in Function[3,2 3+1] should be a symbol or a list of symbols. *)
(* Function[3, 2 3 + 1][9] *)
```

As you see, it seems mathematica provokes an error if you use same variable used in Function[ ], to define a new function.

Looks mathematica wants to prevent a kind of collision of variable names. But I think such thoughtfulness is unnecessary for this case. Function[x, 2 x + 1] just represents a function that maps a thing to its double plus one. After completing interpretation of  the function, we can completely forget the fact : 'the variable used in Function[ ] was x'. What do you think ?

Comment: The main problem is that you are using a delayed assignment `:=`, which redefines the anonymous function every time you call `F`. The problem probably goes away by using an immediate assignment `=`. [Here's a tutorial](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html).

Comment: Similar: [How to prevent name clash between arguments of different functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127294/142).  Using named arguments with `Function` comes with risks that are usually easily avoided by sticking with slot notation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is that to [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)<sup>1</sup> (`:=`), `Function` is just a normal head. For your third example, this means the following: You are defining a downvalue for `F` that says "every time you see `F[something]` replace it with the expression `Function[x, 2 x + 1][x^2]`, where all `x` are to be replaced by `something`". Notice that at no point in that process is the head `Function` treated separately. This means that the `x` inside `Function` is simply replaced by `3` in your example before `Function` has any change to do anything.

Now, there are some functions that *do* treat `Function` differently, e.g. [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html):

```
With[{x = 1}, Function[x, x]]
(* Function[x, x] *)
```

That being said, I do think that your initial statement is pretty much correct: `Function[x,2x+1]` and `2#+1&` are mostly identical, the only issue is that `SetDelayed`<sup>1</sup> knows about neither of them, and will blindly replace parts inside them. You could equally well break the second version:

```
Clear[F]; F[Slot_] := (2 # + 1) &[Slot^2]; F[3]
(* 1 + 2 3[1] *)
```

The only difference here is that there is no error message, and since `#` is `Slot[1]` (and not `Slot`), the failure mode is slightly different, but the point still stands I think.

<sup>1</sup> As noted by Leonid Shifrin in the comments, it is not really accurate to say that the behavior described here is due to `SetDelayed`. `SetDelayed` effectively defines replacement rules (with head [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)), that are then applied using a mechanism similar to [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html). This means that it would be more accurate to say that the rule application mechanism of Mathematica does not know or care about `Function`.

Comment: The first sentence is so impressive "The issue is that to SetDelayed (:=), Function is just a normal head. "  Thank you.

Comment: I would mostly agree with this answer, except I think that the significance of `SetDelayed` here is overemphasized: rather, the main culprit is `RuleDelayed` and rule application in general, while `SetDelayed` simply creates a rule. This is just another manifestation of the well-known fact that rule application does not generally respect inner scoping constructs, not even other delayed rules. Similar problems were discussed in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4435720/565518) (see at the end of that post) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/704/functions-vs-patterns/746#746).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks, that's a very good point! I have added a note to the answer to hopefully clear things up a bit